# Is there is any Free/Open source libraries for compressing the video file /reducing file size of video file in android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

My application deals video sharing. Here i need to reduce the size of videos/ compress the video, so that i can minimize the data upload/download. I went through many threads and most of the threads suggesting FFMPEG. I could integrate it with my application and it is working exactly how i want it to be. But now i came to know that it's a commercial library, and i just have 15 days of trial period. :(

Any other alternatives? Free/open source libraries which satisfies my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg is open source under LGPL - https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html

However it includes tons of different codecs and some external libraries might be non-opensource.

If you are using Android, it already has `MediaCodec` class that can deal with encoding and decoding videos. If you search that, you will find what you need. Very similar topic: [Video compression on android using new MediaCodec Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950610/video-compression-on-android-using-new-mediacodec-library)