# How to change resolution of a video in Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, video, xamarin.forms, camera

I have done a custom camera application in Xamarin.Forms, it takes the videos either with a very low resolution or with a very high resolution.

```
Plugin.Media.Abstraction.VideoQuality.Medium
Plugin.Media.Abstraction.VideoQuality.Low
```

Medium captures video with 1080P and Low with 144P.
I want to have video with 480P or 720P.
How can I change that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code of this nuget, I see that's it's using Android's [EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY) to control the quality of the video. As you can see in the documentation, it allows only values 1 and 0. The nuget uses this logic to determine the value of EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY:

```
private static int GetVideoQuality(VideoQuality videoQuality)
{
    switch (videoQuality)
    {
        case VideoQuality.Medium:
        case VideoQuality.High:
            return 1;

        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

so it's not really possible to easily change the quality to other values. What about resizing the video yourself? Maybe this will start you on this: [Video compression on android using new MediaCodec Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950610/video-compression-on-android-using-new-mediacodec-library)

If you want to change quality of saved photos, you can do it with this property:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    CompressionQuality = 92
});
```

where 0 is max compression and 100 (max) is no compression, it's supported only by iOS and UWP in this plugin.

Here's the documentation I've used: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin